# Trouble Accessing API

Tags: c#, api, blazor

I am trying to pull information from https://covidtracking.com/data/api but I am having an issue. I feel like it has to do with the information being stored in an array. Hopefully someone can push me in write direction. The error it gives me is:

"JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to CovidTracking.Models.CovidDataModel. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."

---

### My code:

```
    CovidDataModel coviddata;
    string errorString;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://api.covidtracking.com/v1/us/current.json");

        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            coviddata = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<CovidDataModel>();
            errorString = null;
        }
        else
        {
            errorString = $"Could not load Covid Data: {response.ReasonPhrase}";
        }
    }
```

---

### Model view below:

```
namespace CovidTracking.Models
{
    public class CovidDataModel
    {
        public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public int Date { get; set; }
        public int States { get; set; }
        public int Positive { get; set; }
        public int Negative { get; set; }

        public int Hospitalized { get; set; }
        public string hash { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Capture the JSON payload you are getting (from within the debugger) and compare it to what you expect (and what your model looks like)

Comment: from the website "Notice: The COVID Tracking Project has ended all data collection as of March 7, 2021. The existing API will continue to work until May 2021, but will only include data up to March 7, 2021."

Comment: On making a request using the enpoint provided in the question, I see you are missing some contents in the model, like `hospitalizedCurrently`. You might need to change the Model

Comment: Just take a look at [What is voting up?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line to:

```
coviddata = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<Class1>>();
```

It means you don't need the class `CovidDataModel` anymore.

```
//public class CovidDataModel
//{
   //public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
//}
```

Comment: What happened? Did it work?